# How can I explain two things concluded from a simulation?

Tags: sentence-construction

Consider:

> The simulation results reveal two important *issues*( I need a better word for issues). 
>   **First**, X is a positive number. **The second**, Y is bigger than Z.

---

Questions:

Q1: Is it fine to use **first** and **the second** similar to what I have written in above ?

Q2: Is there any better option that can be substituted with **issues** ?

Q3: Is there a better sentence? I will be happy to see your comments.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The simulation results reveal two important *issues*. **First**, X is a positive number. **The second**, Y is bigger than Z.

In those sentences there is a couple of places I'd make a change.  First, it's OK to use "issues": one of the meanings is "result", "outcome".  However, with *revealed*, *issues* are assumed to be *pre-existent*, and that points to their meaning as *problems* rather than *results* or *outcome* of the simulation itself.  Perhaps you ought to actually say "results", or rephrase the first sentence and write

> The simulation *leads to the following conclusions*.

Then, there is the beginning of the last sentence.  If you start the second with the word "first", no article, thus making it essentially an adjective, then it is advisable to do the same in the sentence that follows:

> **Second**, Y is bigger than Z.

---

Now, to your questions.

A1: No, if you use "first", then drop the "the" for "second".

A2: You can use "results", "outcomes", or rephrase to avoid using "issues".

A3: I am not sure it's better, but it might be a bit cleaner/clearer:

> The simulation results point to important conclusions.  First, X is a positive number.  Second, Y is bigger than Z.

As you can see, if you already use "first" and "second", perhaps there is no need to announce the number of conclusions.